# If statement in GAWK gives an error

Tags: awk, gawk

I have this piece of code:

```
gawk '{if (match($5,/hola/,a) && $6=="hola") {print $2"\t"$1"\t"$2"\t"$1"\t"$3} else if `(match($5,/(_[joxT]+\.[0-9]*)/,a) && match($6,/(_[joxG]+\.[0-9]*)/,b)) {print $2""a[1]"\t"$1""b[1]} else (match($5,/(_[joxT]+\.[0-9]*)/,a) && $6=="hola") {print "hola"}}' pasted`
```

I'm getting this error:

```
gawk: cmd. line:1: {if (match($5,/hola/,a) && $6=="hola") {print $2"\t"$1"\t"$2"\t"$1"\t"$3} else if (match($5,/(_[joxT]+\.[0-9]*)/,a) && match($6,/(_[joxG]+\.[0-9]*)/,b)) {print $2""a[1]"\t"$1""b[1]} else (match($5,/(_[joxT]+\.[0-9]*)/,a)) {print $1}}
gawk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^ syntax error
```

Do you know where the error is?

Thanks.

Comment: Who voted negative this question?

Comment: The backticks certainly look wrong. If that is not it, split the script over several lines (a newline is allowed anywhere between keywords) so you get a more meaningful error indication. The caret in the error message is actually aligned with the error.

Comment: The downvote is probably due to the lack of any evidence that you have tried to find the error yourself. Have you tried simplifying the command to get something that doesn't have the error, then building up a more complicated command one piece at a time?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
gawk '{if (match($5,/hola/,a) && $6=="hola") {print $2"\t"$1"\t"$2"\t"$1"\t"$3} else if `(match($5,/(_[joxT]+\.[0-9]*)/,a) && match($6,/(_[joxG]+\.[0-9]*)/,b)) {print $2""a[1]"\t"$1""b[1]} else if (match($5,/(_[joxT]+\.[0-9]*)/,a) && $6=="hola") {print "hola"}}' pasted`
```

Answer (score 3):

Take pity on the next guy to maintain your code and indent. Not every program needs to be expressed on one line.

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {OFS = '\t'}
    {
        if ($5 ~ /hola/ && $6 == "hola") {
            print $2, $1, $2, $1, $3
        } 
        else if (match($5, /(_[joxT]+\.[0-9]*)/, a) && match($6, /(_[joxG]+\.[0-9]*)/, b)) {
            print $2 a[1], $1 b[1]
        } 
        else if ($5 ~ /(_[joxT]+\.[0-9]*)/ && $6 == "hola") {
            print "hola"
        }
    }
' pasted
```

Here, only using `match()` when you need to capture part of the match.